# If a metal is placed under 400 kilobar (four hundred thousand atmospheres), how much is it compressed?

Tags: pressure, metals

How much is metal compressed when placed under 400 kilobar (four hundred thousand atmospheres) ?

Comment: Depends on the particular metal, doesn't it? 400 bars is quite a lot of pressure. Wouldn't be surprised to see many metals compress by 20 to 40%, possibly with a pressure-induced structural phase transition or two.

Comment: Oops. I meant 400 kilobars, not bars. Just like the OP said.

Comment: This is exactly what the bulk modulus addresses. And 400 kbar static isn't that much.

Comment: @JonCuster - 400 kbars is not much compared to the maximum pressures achievable by diamond anvil cells, but it is a lot of pressure in the sense that it's enough to make things happen: Significant volume compression for most materials, significant changes in electronic band structure, not uncommon to have one or more structural phase transitions in reaching such pressures, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount a metal compress is the [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) typically ranges from   around 70Gpa for Aluminium to 160Gpa for most Steels

400KBar is 40GPa so in theory 50% of Aluminium and 25% for steel, but the simple law is only really valid for small changes in volume so this is likely to be way off

Comment: Pressures of 400 kbars are way beyond the pressure range where a simple linear pressure-to-volume relation based on the zero-pressure bulk modulus $B_o$  can be used. For those high pressures, a P-V equation-of-state like the Birch-Murnaghan equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch%E2%80%93Murnaghan_equation_of_state) is used, in which both $B_o$ and $B'_o$ are parameters.